# JavaScript Array.filter not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

It seems correct for me, but it doesn't work:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var bar = [2, 4];

arr = arr.filter(function(v) {
  for (var i; i < bar.length; i++) {
    return bar.indexOf(v);
  }
});

console.log(arr); // []

// expected: [1, 3, 5]
```

How this will work, and how to do the same work with map?

Comment: Where are you using `i` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) iterates over the array, you don't need `for` inside `filter`

The problem with `for` inside `filter` is that it'll return the index of the element, which could be `-1`(*truthy*) if not found and anything upto the length of array. And only for the first element i.e. index zero, `filter` will not add the element as zero is falsey in JavaScript.

Also, the `for` loop will only check if the first element of the `bar` and `return` from there.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var bar = [2, 4];

arr = arr.filter(function(v) {
  return bar.indexOf(v) === -1;
});

console.log(arr);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

---

You don't need [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), `map` will transform the array elements with keeping the same number of elements.

---

**ES6:**

Since ES6 you can use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), and arrow functions to make your code look cleaner:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let bar = [2, 4];

arr = arr.filter(v => !bar.includes(v));

console.log(arr);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Agree with answer.  To answer the question of filter and map, filter returns only those elements if the return value in the function is true.  Map returns same number of elements, for the return of false value, the element returned would be undefined.

One more thing, the map return a new array.  Filter does not return a new array.

Comment: @Tushar Can you give me the map example for the same result, just for showcase?

Comment: If used `map` instead of `filter`, you need to use `filter` after map to remove holes [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6ouf9zda/) @elkebirmed

Comment: ES6: `arr.filter(e => !bar.includes(e))`